# Get title of an UIButton located in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I got an UITableView with x UITableViewCell inside. In my cell I got 3 UIButton (callHome, callMobile, sendEmail). Each one got an IBAction. I have to get the title of the UIButton and call/send mail to the data in the title.

I try to catch the title of the button at index x to interact with it, but I can't get it.

Comment: How about getting the title of your button in it's target method itself? Your target method must take an input argument i.e. the button.

Comment: you want to get the button title right ? can you share your IBAction method.

Comment: @n00bprogrammer: I don't understand what you are talking about. Catch the title of an UIButton and do some tasks is very easy without UITableViewCell, but with, it is more difficult.

Comment: @Vineesh TP: NSString *phoneCallNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",myNumber ];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneCallNum]];

Comment: create a delegate for your custom cells, and call back the delegate class when any interaction happens.

Comment: May You can use tag!!

Comment: @holex: but I use at all time the same cell, but the data are changing, according to what I get  from the webservice. For example in my first cell I get "toto@toto.com" and in my second cell I had "guess@guess.com"

Comment: @Saurah How can I do with it please ?

Comment: @Batman, you are not using the _same_ cell, each cell is an individual instance, and if your cell provides the information during the callbacks, you can identify the content without ambiguity. I assume you would have concern about it, because you have never created such design-pattern in your own code, maybe...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch button's target action in ViewController where your UITableView is located you may use blocks. [Block programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Your custom UITableViewCell class interface (.h file):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onButtonClick)(NSString *title); //This is block
```

Then in you custom UITableViewCell implementation (.m file) in button's target method (if you use IB just in UIAction method):

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
  UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
  if (self.onButtonClick) { //Check if block set
     self.onButtonClick(button.titleLabel.text); //Call block
  }
}
```

And then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //...cell configurations
  //...

  cell.onButtonClick = ^void(NSString *title) {
    //do what you want with your button's title
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Click of Every Button Call this Method

```
-(void)callWebService:(id)sender 
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button1"])
{ 
//Action For Button1
}
if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button2"]) 
{
//Action For Button2
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create tableview and then implement delegate methods like below.

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:table];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;

    }
    if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews])
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button2 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(bMethod:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, button2.frame.size.height+50, 160.0, 40.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];


    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    return 200;
}
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"button title:%@",button.currentTitle);

}
-(void)bMethod:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"button title:%@",button.currentTitle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the title of the button.

You can get the title of the button by using  `sender.currentTitle`

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{

NSString *title = sender.currentTitle;

}
```